# Query error when testing in Database SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have this query and appearently it's faulty?
I'm trying to join `fices` with `mems` so I can have the `ficeID` along with all the results from `mems`(These queries work individually). What am I doing wrong?

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM mems 
   WHERE deleted <> -1 
ORDER BY sort_mems 
         LEFT JOIN SELECT ficeID 
                     FROM fices
```

Result:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN SELECT ficeID FROM offices LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

Comment: `Join` statement should always be before the `where` clause and after `from`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have `JOIN` clause after `ORDER BY`. You should place it in `FROM`.
- I suggest you define condition of a `LEFT JOIN`
- Also, I suggest you surround you temp tables with brackets:

  ```
    SELECT m.*, t1.officeID
      FROM members m
           LEFT JOIN offices t1
                     ON m.memberID = t1.memberID
     WHERE m.deleted <> -1 
  ORDER BY m.sort_membername;
  ```

Comment: I get this:  #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE deleted <> -1 ORDER BY sort_mems LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: @TopDecker provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE mems;` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE fices;` outputs, and I'll give your the query you need

Comment: The outputs are huge though.

Comment: Hmm I get Column 'deleted' in where clause is ambiguous that means we're close I guess..

Comment: You nailed it perfect!!! Thanks so much!! I need to learn more about SQL do you maybe have a good source?

Comment: @TopDecker yw. We'd done it faster, if you'd provided `SHOW CREATE`s at the begining.

Comment: My bad i'll provide from now on regarding SQL issues.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have the `LEFT JOIN` in the wrong spot (it should go after your `FROM` clause, and you also seem to be missing a join criteria (the `ON` part, this tells the database how these tables are related):

```
SELECT *
FROM mems m
LEFT JOIN fices f
  ON  m.??? = f.???
WHERE deleted <> -1 
ORDER BY sort_mems
```

Comment: Well, for one, I had a typo... one of those should have been an `f`.  However, the `ON` clause is a statement that lets you define how the two tables are related. For example, if you had an `employee` table, and each employee belonged to a `department` in a company, and you wanted to get data from both tables, you might do something like...   `SELECT ... FROM employee e JOIN department d ON e.dept_id = d.id WHERE ...`

Comment: Ohhh I get it now i'll try that and report in in a sec

Comment: I tried it and this was my result:  Column 'deleted' in where clause is ambiguous